# What are the advantages of using `require` inside a module instead of at the top?

Tags: ruby

Usually, I put most of my `require` statements at the top of a file. While reading the source code for Poltergeist, I noticed the following

```
module Capybara
  module Poltergeist
    require 'capybara/poltergeist/utility'
    require 'capybara/poltergeist/driver'
    require 'capybara/poltergeist/browser'
    # more requires
  end
end
```

[Actual source](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist/blob/master/lib/capybara/poltergeist.rb)

What are the advantages of using `require` this way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The advantage in this case is that the `Capybara::Poltergeist` module exists before those modules are required. Since those modules all extend the `Capybara::Poltergeist` module, this is just a way to ensure that they aren't loaded before the module is actually available. Placing the require statements after the module definition would have the same effect.

Consider the following:

```
# foobar.rb
require './bar_module'

module Foo
  module Bar
  end
end

# bar_module.rb
module Foo::Bar
   def baz
     "hi!"
   end
end
```

This setup will fail because the non-nested `Foo::Bar` syntax will expect `Foo` to already exist by the time this module is called. By changing the first file to:

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    require './bar_module'
  end
end
```

The require will work, since `Foo::Bar` will exist by the time that `bar_module` starts doing its thing.

In this particular instance, it doesn't have much practical effect, since Poltergeist uses the nested module syntax (`module Foo; module Bar`) rather than the collapsed syntax (`module Foo::Bar`), but it's a good practice that basically delineates "these requires expect this module to exist".

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what's the advantage in your example.

I sometimes use `require` inside a method definition.

I do this for methods which are used rarely, but need large libraries. The advantage: The large library is only loaded, when it is really needed.

`require` checks, if the library is already loaded. So I have no problem with double loading a library.

Comment: Would not it be better to use the autoload method instead of inserting the require within the method? I think it would be a more elegant solution, since I would load it only when needed on the call