# In Ruby, do i require within a class or outside?

Tags: ruby, oop

If i want to make a class :

```
class Foo
    #methods here
end
```

that requires lets say `FileUtils`

do i do

```
require 'fileutils'

class Foo
    #methods here
end
```

or

```
class Foo
    require 'fileutils'
    #methods here
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the advantages of using \`require\` inside a module instead of at the top?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258838/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-require-inside-a-module-instead-of-at-the-top)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work either way. `require` works anywhere, and the `FileUtils` will be available inside and outside of your class.

By what I have seen on github, it is usually on top - just like most of the other languages, by the way.

Comment: I was thinking if i require it within the class, when i instantiate it, will the require line get unnecessarily executed or called ?leading to unnecessary overhead

Comment: @GeorgeAnandaEman If it is in your class body it will be called only once, but if is a method call, it will be called every time you call that method.

Answer (score 5):

To complement fotanus's answer. Anything defined on a separate file rests in the `main` namespace, wherever you `load` or `require` it from. It does not make difference in terms of scope or namespace. Furthermore, local variables cannot be referenced across files.

So your choice should depend on maintainability. If you write the dependencies on the top of the file, it is easy to know the dependency at a glance. On the other hand, if you require within  a certain module, it can make it clear that that dependency is only for the particular module. In the older days, I think the former was preferred, but nowadays, where people use the `bundler` gem, there is a means to see all the dependencies at a glance, so the motivation for the former may have declined.